# Add only key without value to query params

Tags: typescript, http, request

I try to send one strange request to bugzilla, and I need to add to query only key, without value.

Example:

```
bugzilla.com/rest/bug?resolution=FIXED&resolution=
```

I use typescript, and now, my code looks like:

```
let params = new HttpParams();
params = params.append('resolution', 'FIXED');
this.http.get('http://bugzilla.com/rest/bug', { params: params });
```

When I try to use:

```
append('resolution', '')
```

the result is wrong - I get:  `resolution=""`

- `append('resolution', undefined)` turns into a wrong result, too:  `resolution=undefined`
- `append('resolution', null)` also doesn't work and returns  `resolution=null`

Can anybody help with this?

Comment: If all the result are wrong, what do you want as result ?

Comment: @JonathanDelean, I want to take `resolution=`

Comment: resolution="" is the same thing than resolution= , why you dont have the double quotes ?

Comment: `bugzilla.com/rest/bug?resolution=` - this url I want to take, not `bugzilla.com/rest/bug?resolution=""`. It is importent, because if I use `""` for key, bugzilla will try to find bugs by resolution field with empty string. But if I use `resolution=`, bugzilla will try to find bugs without any resolution (all open bugs).

Comment: I know, it is very strange, but is a official way
https://bugzilla.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/core/v1/bug.html

> resolution - The current resolution--only set if a bug is closed. You can find open bugs by searching for bugs with an empty resolution.

Answer (score 0):

If you send `resolution=` or nothing, it's the same thing, for bugzilla too i think

Comment: Yes, but I want to take bugs with field `resolution=FIXED` AND without resolution. In this case, need to send request `bugzilla.com/rest/bug?resolution=FIXED&resolution=`

Answer (score 0):

I found answer, but it will work only for bugzilla

In request, `key=---` - is a "no key", it work in bugzilla.

Request `bugzilla.com/rest/bug?resolution=FIXED&resolution=---` to take all bugs with resolution=FIXED and without any resulution.

In documentation I see `target_milestone` value describe:

> The Target Milestone field of a bug. Note that even if this Bugzilla does not have the Target Milestone field enabled, you can still search for bugs by Target Milestone. However, it is likely that in that case, most bugs will not have a Target Milestone set (it defaults to "---" when the field isn't enabled).

Value `---`(not `"---"`, it wrong) when field isn't enabled, and this rule work for all of fields